# Python conditional statements

Tags: python, conditional-statements

```
def Fitness(a, b, c):  
    if ((a&b&c) >= 4) & ((a+b+c) >= 13):  
        return('Gold')  
    if ((a&b&c) >= 3) & ((a+b+c) >= 10):  
        return('Silver')   
    if ((a&b&c) >= 2) & ((a+b+c) >= 07):  
        return('Pass')  
    else:  
        return('Fail')
```

now the Problem is  when `Fitness(2,2,5)` is given, the control jumps to default ie. 'Fail'.
Where is the actual output is 'Pass'. ?

Comment: Could you explain the logic you're trying to implement?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Note that

```
a&b&c >= 2
```

is different from

```
a>=2 and b>=2 and c>=2.
```

I think you mean the second one, i.e. all values are larger than two. (The first one does a [binary and](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations) with all your values and compares this to the value two.)

Comment: Ah! +1 for best use of crystal ball today!

Answer (score 6):

Use `and` instead of `&` (binary and). And don't write `07` - numbers starting with `0` may be interpreted as octal depending on your version of Python.

Together with Howard's inspiration, I'd suggest this:

```
def Fitness(a, b, c):
    if all(x>=4 for x in (a,b,c)) and (a+b+c) >= 13:
        return('Gold')
    if all(x>=3 for x in (a,b,c)) and (a+b+c) >= 10:
        return('Silver') 
    if all(x>=2 for x in (a,b,c)) and (a+b+c) >= 7:
        return('Pass')
    return('Fail')
```

Also, it's sad that you're not awarding a bronze medal...

Comment: I'm not sure this should be causing the problem. `True` is 1 and `False` is 0, so `True & True` should still give `True`, `True & False` should still give `False`, etc.

Comment: @Chris: Right. I've just checked that after many subtle corrections to his code to get it to run at all. Clarification by the OP needed.

Comment: hmm...(a&b&c)>= no, causes problems, if a=b it goes to default condition. i m not sure!!

Comment: used (a>=no) & (b>=no) & .... instead, i like to know why the latter doesn't work

Comment: Type `2&2&5` into a Python shell and see for yourself. `0b010` binary and `0b101` is `0`. Don't confuse logical `and` with binary `&`!

Answer (score 3):

> Where is the actual output is 'Pass'.

No it isn't. 2 (0b010) & 2 & 5 (0b101) is 0, so the expressions will all fail even if you change the `&` separating the two terms to `and`. Perhaps you meant to use a completely different expression?

Comment: By "where the actual output is", he seems to mean "where the actual output should be".

Answer (score 2):

I'd post this as a comment to Tim Pietzcker's answer, since it's just an improvement on it, but the comment field would mess up the formatting, so I'm making it a separate answer.

```
def fitness(*args):
    arg_sum = sum(args)
    smallest_arg = min(args)

    if smallest_arg >= 4 and arg_sum >= 13:
        return 'Gold'
    if smallest_arg >= 3 and arg_sum >= 10:
        return 'Silver'
    if smallest_arg >= 2 and arg_sum >= 7:
        return 'Pass'
    return 'Fail'
```

First the important stuff:

1. Enclosing the return value in parenthesis like in `return('Gold')` is not wrong per se, but will confuse the reader; `return` is a statement, not a function. It works nontheless because the parenthesis are in effect [silently ignored](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences). If what you wanted was in fact to return a tuple with a single string element, do `return ('Gold',)`.
2. [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself): Compute the sum and smallest element of the arguments once, and use the computed values in the `if` blocks, as shown above.
3. Since the arguments are all treated equally and together, gather them in an `*args` tuple. This will also generalize the function to work with any number of arguments. If that should not be allowed, add this to the beginning of the function:

   ```
   if len(args) != 3:
       raise TypeError("Need exactly 3 arguments, got {0}".format(len(args)))
   ```

Finally I'll just mention that functions should have `lower_case_names` according to the [python style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Following the style guide is of course not mandatory, just recommended. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
def fitness(*args):
    arg_sum = sum(args)
    smallest_arg = min(args)

    if smallest_arg >= 4 and arg_sum >= 13:
        return 'Gold'
    if smallest_arg >= 3 and arg_sum >= 10:
        return 'Silver'
    if smallest_arg >= 2 and arg_sum >= 7:
        return 'Pass'
    return 'Fail'
```